# Azure Data Factory V2 extracting Dynamics CRM Data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to extract the data entities from Dynamics CRM 365 and facing an issue. In the Data Factory, I am using Query based Copy Activity and specifying all the fields that needs to be extracted but in the Sink side I see only a partial result.
I have around 200 fields on the source side and seeing only 70 fields in the sink. When I try to run the same query (FetchXML) in XRMToolBox, I get all the fields as expected.

It seems like a know issue sometime back in Azure Data Factory following this link - [link1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21216) but even following the suggestions from the thread like sorting, adding the fields in addition to 'all-attributes' I am still not getting all the fields from CRM. I made the fields I am pulling are supported by Data Factory - [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#dynamics-as-a-source-type)

Sample Fetch XML:

```
<fetch>
<entity name="invoice" />
<all-attributes/>
<attribute name="po_relatedquoteid" />     
</fetch>
```

In the sink side, I am not seeing the field 'po_relatedquoteid'. Appreciate any inputs how to pull all the fields from CRM.

Comment: Does your field po_relatedquoteid has some data. Fetchxml will exclude fields which does not have data.

Comment: Yes it does, as mentioned when I run the query using XRMtoolbox I can see the field values.